# Rstudio Fatal Error on startup - R error 4

Tags: r, rstudio, fatal-error

I have had the below error for the second time when starting up R studio in the space of a month. Last time I uninstalled R Studio and then re-installed it which fixed the issue however now its back. Unfortunately I am on a work laptop without admin rights so I am limited on what I can do on my end however I was wondering if anyone knows what the error really means and how to resolve it?

Ive done some research on similar errors however I haven't found any resources for this error.

Thank you!

```
The R session had a fatal error.

12 Sep 2020 14:47:43 [rsession-username] ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg: Error in (function (reposUrl) : unused argument ("")
]; OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::evaluateExpressionsUnsafe(struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC *,struct SEXPREC **,class rstudio::r::sexp::Protect *,enum rstudio::r::exec::`anonymous-namespace'::EvalType) src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:171
```

Comment: This error occurs when RStudio can’t find the installation of R. Can you check if R is loading properly while starting RStudio?